# Regular Expression for HTML artifacts

Tags: python, html, regex

I some text with HTML artifacts where the `<` and `>` of tags got dropped, so now I need something that will match a small `p` followed by a capital letter, like

```
pThe next day they....
```

And I also need something that will catch the trailing `/p` which is easier. These need to be stripped, i.e. replaced with `""` in python.

What RE would I use for that? Thanks!
 Stephan.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r"(/?p)(?=[A-Z]|$)", r"<\1>", str)
```

You might want to extend the boundary assertion (here `(?=[A-Z]|$)`) with additional characters like whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I got is. You use backreferences,

```
import re
smallBig = re.compile(r'[a-z]([A-Z])')

...
cleanedString = smallBig.sub(r'\1', dirtyString)
```

This removes the small letter but keeps the capital letter in cases where the '<' and '>' of html tags were stripped and you sit with text like

pSome new paragraph text /p

Quick and dirty but it works in my case.